# Suppose there is an array with 0, 1 and 5 in it. '5' can be replaced by either 0 or 1. How to find the length of longest continuing character?

Tags: arrays, sorting, search, data-structures

**Suppose there is an array with 0, 1 and 5 in it. 5 can be replaced by either 0 or 1. How to find the length of longest continuing character?**

1. Suppose array is 051. In this case we can replace 5 by 0 or 1. So it will become 001 or 011. In both the cases the length of longest continuing character is 2.
2. Suppose if array is 0511 now 5 has to be replaced with 1 to get longest continuing character in 0111. If 5 is replace by 0 we get 0011 and longest continuing character becomes 2, this is less than 3. Therefore length of longest continuing character is 3.

**3. This has to be done in one iteration of array**

Some Examples:

INPUT: 15015001. OUTPUT: 3

Explanation: *15015001* -> *11010001* -> we have 3 zeros together so length of longest continuing character is 3.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: How about you give it a try? Then, if you need some help, post your code along with a description of what it does, and *specific questions* about where you're having problems. We're not here to just write code for you.

Comment: Hey Jim
Not asking for code. Just need to know how you would approach this kind of question. I have few ideas but all of them are failing at some point. I will list out those ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Check each character:

- If it's a 0, increment my zero-counter and set my one-counter to 0
- If it's a 1, increment my one-counter and set my zero-counter to 0
- If it's a 5, increment both my zero-counter and my one-counter
- Check the value of both counters.  If either of them is greater than the current value of my longest-set , then update my longest-set to that value.

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for the answer.

This fails for {1, 5, 0, 0, 1}.
Expected output: 3 as (1,0,0,0,1)
Actual output: 1

Comment: @SaurabhKumar: Following his algorithm by hand, I get an output of 3, as expected. I don't see how you get the value 1.

Comment: in {1,5,0,0,1} when the last character I encounter as 1, then I have to set my zero-counter to 0 from 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getLongestContinousCharLength(int[] array) {
        int count0 = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int maxCount1 = 0;
        int maxCount0 = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < array.length) {
            if (array[i] == 0) {
                count0++;
                count1 = 0;
                if (count0 > maxCount0)
                    maxCount0 = count0;
            } else if (array[i] == 1) {
                count1++;
                count0 = 0;
                if (count1 > maxCount1)
                    maxCount1 = count1;
            } else {
                count0++;
                if (count0 > maxCount0)
                    maxCount0 = count0;
                count1++;
                if (count1 > maxCount1)
                    maxCount1 = count1;

            }
            i++;
        }
        return maxCount0 > maxCount1 ? maxCount0 : maxCount1;
    }
```